# Angular Validation based on selected option in DropDown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, drop-down-menu

I am working on a project that relies heavily on Angular for its front-end. I am still in the process of learning Angular, and have come across a complex scenario.

Here is what I have:

[image: Dropdown with options]

The above is part of a wizard. Clicking `Next` moves the user along the wizard. So far so good. I do not want the user to be able to click `Next` unless they select an option from the drop down.

If they select the `Payment Taken` option, I would like them to be able to move along the wizard, but instead what is currently happening is this:

[image: Payment Taken option selected in Drop Down]

As you can see, the `Next` button is disabled when I want it to be enabled.

Moving on .. if `Payment Deferred` is selected, I would like the user to input a reason for why the payment was deferred .. also this reason must be over 10 characters long, if that rule is satisfied, then the `Next` button should be enabled.

[image: Payment Deferred option selected]

The above seems to work fine!

**CODE:**

```
<form name="paymentForm">
    <div class="form-group" id="Div2">
        <select ng-model="selectedPaymentStatus" ng-options="ps.name for ps in paymentStatus" required></select>
    </div><!-- .form_group -->

    <div ng-show="selectedPaymentStatus.value === 'paymentDeferred'" class="form-group" id="Div3">
        <p>Reason</p>
        <textarea class="form-control" ng-disabled="selectedPaymentStatus.value === 'paymentTaken'" required ng-model="crate.paymentDeferredReason" ng-minlength="10"></textarea>
    </div><!-- .form_group -->
</form>

<button class="btn wizard-next-btn pull-right" ng-disabled="!paymentForm.$valid" ng-click="nextStep()">Next</button>
<button class="btn wizard-back-btn" ng-click="previousStep()">Back</button>
```

**WHAT I THINK:**

I think the reason it is not behaving as expected when I select `Payment Taken` in the drop down is because I have told my markup that the hidden `Reason` textarea is also required.

To get over this, I made my `Reason` text area disabled when the user selects `Payment Deferred`.

```
ng-disabled="selectedPaymentStatus.value === 'paymentTaken'"
```

But this apparently does not override the validation rules set on that DOM element (the textarea); that, or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: As a quick idea, can you replace `ng-show` with `ng-if` (Angular >= 1.2)? `ng-if` removes the element and, hopefully, may also retract the validation failure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ng-show` applies the `display: none` CSS rule ([ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)), but the functionality of the content is still present. In your case, the `<textarea>` remains required, despite the block being hidden.

`ng-if` on the other hand completely removes its content from the DOM *and* Angular's hierarchy. The removed `ng-model` controller will *not* take part in validation, which is what you want:

```
<div ng-if="selectedPaymentStatus.value === 'paymentDeferred'" ...>
    <textarea ...>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Nikos, you know a lot about Angular :)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
<ng-container *ngIf="selectedPaymentStatus.value === 'paymentDeferred;">
   <div>
      <textarea> Some Text Goes Here </textarea>
   </div>
</ng-container>
```